# How can sort paragraph fields of custom content type?

Tags: views, nodes, entities, paragraphs

I created a content type that’s combination of some typical fields and one paragraph type field and inside of this paragraph field also there are a set of multiple fields.
The schematic structure of my content type is like below:

[image]

I want to have this ability to add some of this paragraph type and update this content type every time that I want.

However, in the 'add field' section of the view creation page, I can only select the `main content fields`. The fields that are part of the Paragraph are not selectable.

How can I get the fields from the paragraph so that I can sort them in the view results?

So my main question is:
How can I sort this paragraph field (with a set of fields inside it) based on the custom required field value automatically?

For example, I want to sort those paragraph filed based on `paragraph_field_2` field.
Is there any better solution or method for doing this work, What’s your approach to it?
thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a View, rather than paragraphs. Create a custom type with the required fields, and sort by `paragraph_field_2`. Paragraphs are supposed to be ordered manually by the content editor.

Comment: Thanks, but this paragraph field with its inner fields can repeat, and I want to have multiple of this paragraph field in my node.

Comment: Create multiple nodes of content type `B`. Create a View that with the filter and sorting that you want. Embed the View in the node view of content type `A`.

Comment: @Tim: Thank you so much for your help and reply. Can you help me and explain a little more about your approach please, Thanks.

Comment: Why are you reordering paragraphs based on a paragraph value instead of just letting the user dictate the order in the UI?

Comment: @Kevin: I want to my paragraphs field sort base on variable fields like `download rate` or `user votes` field.

Comment: @Kevin: I want to create an `Application Review and Compare` content type.